# How with eloquent pull lists and sorted connected taks

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How with eloquent pull lists and sorted connected tasks to those list(something like this

```
$classes = Classes::find(1)->student;
```

but for all lists(for example I thought this will work but sadly no)

```
$lists = Lists::all()->task;
```

Comment: Try `$lists = Lists::withTask()->all();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that a task belongs to a list, you can do it like so :

```
foreach(Lists::all() as $list) {
   // do something with $list->task
}
```

Comment: see that is interesting approach you take it as an collection and then reiterate trough it